# Visual Studio setup add custom file using environment variables

Tags: c#, windows, configuration, wix, installation

I have created a **Visual Studio Installer - Setup** project to install my application.

I'm storing the content in `[CommonAppDataFolder][Manufacturer]\[ProductName]`. I want to create a file in the target machine with path to the files under `[CommonAppDataFolder][Manufacturer]\[ProductName]`.

- How do I achieve this?
- How do I use environment variables in client machine to generate the path to the files, and write in a file during the deployment?
- How do I have to use Wix\buy InstallShield to achieve the customization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't tagged this as setup project, and I don't think you're using the WiX add-on to VS so:

You can right-click on Target Machine in the file system view and Add Special Folder, Custom folder. Set the DefaultLocation to [CommonAppDataFolder][Manufacturer]\ProductName]

CommonAppDataFolder isn't in the drop-down list on my VS version, so you may need to type it in. Once you've got that custom folder you can drag your files tp it, as you probably know.

Comment: Do you know of any place where I could see all such variables which are not in the dropdown list? I'm looking for "common startup folder" variable, but can't find it anywhere.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370905(v=vs.85).aspx#system_folder_properties